# Calculate conditional means in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 100], [1, 2, 101], [1, 3, 102], 
                     [2, 1, 103], [2, 2, 104], [2, 3, 105], 
                     [3, 1, 106] ,[3, 2, 107], [3, 3, 108]],
                    columns=['row', 'column', 'cell value'])
```

Each row of data represents the value and location (by 'row' and 'column') of a cell. What I am hoping to do is to calculate the mean cell value of the adjacent cells for each cell. For example, for cell (row==2 column==2), I need the mean cell value calculated from:

- cell value (row==1,column==2)
- cell value (row==3,column==2)
- cell value (row==2,column==1)
- cell value (row==2,column==3)

I need to apply this calculation to every cell.

I have the following defined functions:

This function extracts the cell value for a particular cell:

```
def val(r,c):
    return float(data['cell value'][(data['row'] == r) & (data['column'] == c)])
```

This function extracts the adjacent cell values:

```
def adjval(r,c): 
    adj = []
    if r != data['row'].max(): 
        adj.append(thick(r + 1, c))
    if r!=1: 
        adj.append(thick(r - 1, c))
    if c!=data['column'].max(): 
        adj.append(thick(r, c + 1))
    if c!=1: 
        adj.append(thick(r, c - 1))
    return adj
```

But then I am struggling to find a way to apply this function to each cell in the dataframe. I tried `iterrows` but it was very slow as the actual dataset is very large.

Any advice on how I can proceed forward will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is complexity here that could go away if an ordinary 2 dimensional numpy array were used.

Comment: Also, for an edge or corner, what should happen? For example, the vertical and horizontal neighbors of a corner point have only 2 neighbors, and a side point will only have 3 neighbors, unless some kind of wrapping occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Paul, I will look into the 2D numpy array. And for an edge or corner, yes you are right that the mean will need to be calculated from 2/3 neighbors only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Paul suggests, you probably want to use numpy here.  Numpy is a dependency of pandas and well worth learning both on it's own and as a companion to pandas.  For cases where you don't really need the additional features of pandas, the numpy solution can be much faster.  This is one of those cases.

The trickiest part of this is the corners and edges, which I have dealt with by putting a ring of NaNs around the outside.  In combination with `np.nanmean` (instead of `np.mean`) this will keep the denominator correct for calculating means.  There may (or may not) be a more elegant way to do this although it's already a fairly concise answer as it stands.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.empty([5,5])
arr[:] = np.nan
arr[1:4,1:4] = np.arange(100,109).reshape(3,3)
```

Or alternatively, if you need to convert from your original dataframe into a numpy array, then you can replace the last line with:

```
arr[1:4,1:4] = data.set_index(['row','column']).unstack().values
```

So now your array looks like this.

```
array([[  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,  100.,  101.,  102.,   nan],
       [  nan,  103.,  104.,  105.,   nan],
       [  nan,  106.,  107.,  108.,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan]])
```

And `np.nanmean` is all you need after that.

```
np.nanmean( np.array( [ arr[1-1:4-1,1:4], arr[1:4,1-1:4-1], 
                        arr[1+1:4+1,1:4], arr[1:4,1+1:4+1] ] ), axis=0 )

array([[ 102.        ,  102.        ,  103.        ],
       [ 103.33333333,  104.        ,  104.66666667],
       [ 105.        ,  106.        ,  106.        ]])
```